# No dispatch.fcgi on ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iis, redmine

I'm trying to interface redmine to IIS 6. It works fine under webrick.

So I tried to create a new rails app to reduce the complexity, but that doesn't create the dispatch.fcgi file in the public folder, which leads me to think that my RubyIIS setup is wrong.

What am I doing wrong here? I have no idea about ruby or rails, so need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine ships a `dispatch.fcgi.example` file in its distribution. Just rename it and you should be ready to go.

But note that there is only sparse support for Redmine on fcgi. I heard many people have issues there. So you might think about switching away from fcgi here to a more supported (and more common) solution. That would be using your $WEBSERVER (IIS in that case) as a loadbalancing proxy in front of a couple of Mongrels hosting the Redmine.

I'm not 100% sure if an IIS is able to fulfull all your needs here (being a Unix guy myself). You might want to switch to Apache instead :)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree. After beating my head against a brick (IIS fcgi) for a couple of days, I gave up and switched IIS to 8080 and fronted it with Apache on 80. Ran redmine on a Mongrels cluster and reverse proxied to that for my redmine url from Apache on one virtual host and used a second virtual host to reverse proxy to IIS.

Unfortunately, IIS 6 cannot be used as a proxy, so had to use Apache.